# Return a string with characters that come one after the other using while loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop

How are you =)

I have task to return string with characters "@" "#" one after another with string length of 5 using While loop.

I have an idea to assign "@" to odd numbers, "#" to even numbers.

Where "@" is 0, "#" is 1, "@" is 2, and so on until the end of the length of the line.
Unfortunately, I can't find information how I can do this.

Please check the following code, I hope it will be more clear what I am talking about.

I will be glad for any hint or advice, thank you :)

```
public String drawLine(int length) {
    int i = 0;
    
        while (i < length) {
        
            //I know that the following code will take only the int length, it's just an idea
            if(length % 2 == 0) {
                i++;
                System.out.print("@");
            }
            else {
                i++;
                System.out.print("#");
            }
        }
        
    return new String("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JustATest helper = new JustATest();

    //The result should be @#@#@
    System.out.println(helper.drawLine(5));
}
```

Comment: you are only returning "" you'll need to build that String, not print those symbols in that method

Comment: you should be checking the modulo of `i` not `length`

Comment: @Stultuske is right. @Bentaye is right too. Check out `StringBuilder.append`

Comment: Hi @Stultuske =), I made same thing in my previous task, where I had to return rectangle, it worked fine, please check the following code

Comment: public String drawQuad(int n) {

   int i = 0;

   while (i++ < n) {
    int j = 0;

    while (j++ < n) {
     System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
   return new String("");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArlanHelper helper = new ArlanHelper();
        //Should be:
        //XX
        //XX
        //XX
        System.out.println(helper.drawRect(2, 3, 'X'));
    }
}

Comment: @OrestDymarchuk if I were your teacher, you would have failed big time, since that code doesn't do what it should do. All it returns is an empty String

Comment: I will try to solve the previous task using different methods, thanks for the mentioned mistake @Stultuske

Comment: it's not as much your method you need to change. Instead of printing those symbols, add them to the builder. and return builder.toString(); at the end of the method

Comment: I will check the info regarding the builder.toString(); 
Never use it before. @Stultuske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we've two address two issues here as some have already pointed out in the comments beneath your questions.

You define in your question that your task is to **return** the final string instead of printing it directly. For such things you can either use a `StringBuiler` (see my example below) or simply concatenate in any other way ( e.g. `"A" + "B" -> "AB"`)

The second issue is the iteration itself. You use mod 2 to determine if the value you test is even or not. This part is correct. However you're always comparing the desired length `length % 2 == 0` instead of the current position `i` of the character to print. Therefore you'll only ever print `@` or `#` `length`-times depending on the desired length being even (leading to `@`) or odd (leading to `#`).

Below you can find my example on how to properly solve your task. Simply exchange `length` within the `if` clause with `i` and concatenate the result and return it.

```
 public String drawLine(int length)
{
    int i = 0;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while ( i < length )
    {
        //I know that the following code will take only the int length, it's just an idea
        if( i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            i++;
            builder.append( "@" );
        } else
        {
            i++;
            builder.append( "#" );
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```